# Python: Dictionary in another dictionary

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary

i've got a problem with dictionaries in python.

I have a Dataframe with approx. 700 rows. Each row is a dictionary (key-value pair), where the value is also a dictionary. The problem is by casting the cells of the Dataframe into dict's, it also cast the values as a string. Now i want to cast these values back to dictionaries again, without missing the key.

Example: Transform `{'Key1':'{1:value1, 2:value2, 3:value3, 4:value4}'}` into `{'Key1': {'1':'value1','2':'value2','3':'value3','4':'value4'}}`

Thanks for your help :)

P.S.: i would like to apologize in advance for spelling mistakes and grammatical mistakes

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've tried to convert into json, the package ast and re.....

Comment: Please share whatever you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more details. Mostly what you describe, should work.

```
a = {'Key1':{1:'1.1', 2:'2.2', 3:'3.3', 4:'4.4'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
print(df.to_dict())
```

Output:

```
  Key1
1  1.1
2  2.2
3  3.3
4  4.4
{'Key1': {1: '1.1', 2: '2.2', 3: '3.3', 4: '4.4'}}
```

Is this a dataframe structure you consider?

Answer (score 0):

## Output

```
[{'b':'{1: N, 2: ((49, 1), (52, 1), (2726440, 1000000)), 3: E, 4: ((8, 1), (38, 1), 
(17371673, 1000000)), 6: (22480, 100), 7: ((16, 1), (0, 1), (9, 1)), 29: 
2018:11:29}','b':'{1: e, 2: ((80, 5), (5, 3), (2726440, 1000546)), 3: N, 4: ((3, 1), 
(38, 1), (17371673, 1000000)), 6: (22980, 100), 7: ((16, 1), (0, 1), (9, 1)), 29: 
2018:11:29}','b': ..... }]
```

## Code

```
data = data.rename(columns={'a','b'}) 
data_dict = data.to_dict('records')
```

## Deskription

So i got this so far:
data is a dataframe with 1 column with the dictionaries(700 rows);
i renamed the column to 'b', because it should be the key for all dictionaries in the dictionary; now i got a list with 700 dictionaries with the output form